# Why does $\oint_C \vec{E}\cdot d\vec{\ell}=0$ imply $\nabla\times \vec{E}=\vec{0}$?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, differential-geometry, maxwell-equations, mathematics

In electromagnetism, the circulation of the $\vec{E}$ field is zero,
\begin{equation}
\oint_C \vec{E}\cdot d\vec{\ell}=0.
\end{equation}
With Stokes law, this implies that
\begin{equation}
\int_S \nabla\times \vec{E}\cdot d\vec{A}=0.
\end{equation}
*The usual argument*: As this must be true for any surface $S$, the second equation implies that $ \nabla\times \vec{E}=\vec{0}$.

**Question**: Why does the second equation imply $ \nabla\times \vec{E}=\vec{0}$, but the first equation does not imply $\vec{E}=\vec{0}$? After all, the first equation also holds for any closed loop $C$. What types of integrals are amenable to this line of reasoning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first equation is only for all **closed** loops, not for all contours. That’s why you can’t conclude $\vec{E}=0$. The only thing you can conclude is that $\vec{E}=\text{grad}(V)$ for some function $V$.

If instead you had a vector function $F:U\subset \Bbb{R}^n\to\Bbb{R}^n$ (where $U\subset\Bbb{R}^n$ is open) such that for **all** (smooth enough) contours $\Gamma$ lying in $U$, $\int_{\Gamma}F\cdot dl=0$, then you *can* conclude that $F=0$ identically in $U$.

Even if not directly obvious, all such statements are going to be minor modifications of the *fundamental lemma of calculus of variations*.

---

To understand this geometrically, imagine the following scenrios:

- First, consider 1 dimension. So, consider a smooth function $f:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ such that $\int_x^xf(t)\,dt=0$ for all $x$. Well, this is kind of silly because every function $f$ satisfies this, no matter how crazy, so of course it doesn’t imply $f=0$.
- perhaps a slightly less fringe case might be more illuminating. In two dimensions, consider $F(x,y)=(1,0)=e_1$, i.e the vector field which constantly points to the right (it is the gradient of $f(x,y)=x$). Then, integrating over any closed loop (for example closed rectangle) gives $0$, but $F$ itself is not $0$. The reason is that when you allow the loop to close in on itself, you allow for there to be **cancellations** in the integral. For example, take a rectangular loop. Then, the integrals over the top and bottom edges are non-zero but they will cancel out, since when you traverse the loop, you’ll traverse them in opposite directions. The integrals over the right and left edges cancel out for the same reason (actually, for this specific example, the integrals over the right and left edges vanishes, since the vector field is *normal* to the edges, as it points to the right).

Answer (score 2):

For the very reason you say at the end of your question: while the second relation holds **for all surfaces**, the first one only holds **for all closed loops**, and not any arbitrary line.

---

Let's do some examples about similar cases, switching the role of closed and open regions and the role of line and surfaces.

- On one hand, if you have an integral relation
  $$\int_{\ell} \mathbf{F} = \mathbf{0} \qquad , \qquad \forall \ell \ ,$$
  thus, this implies $\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{r}) = \mathbf{0}$.
- On the other hand, if you have a surface integral relation on a closed surface
  $$\oint_{S} \mathbf{F} \cdot \mathbf{\hat{n}} = \mathbf{0} \qquad , \qquad \forall S \text{ closed} \ ,$$
  this doesn't imply $\mathbf{F} = \mathbf{0}$ but, if we deal with "regular enough" fields, it implies that such a vector field is divergence-free,
  $$\nabla \cdot \mathbf{F}(\mathbf{r}) = 0 \ ,$$
  and thus it can be written as a curl of a vector field $\mathbf{G}(\mathbf{r})$,
  $$\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{r}) = \nabla \times \mathbf{G}(\mathbf{r}) \ .$$